# Trouble redirecting .txt file to stdin

Tags: c

I want to redirect file to stdin

So I use .txt to test and practice. The tutorial says that redirection is like copying the content of the file to the stdin, and wrtie what should appear in the command window to another file

So, here is my code

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    printf("%d arguments\n", argc);
    for(argv; *(argv); printf("%s\n", *(argv)), argv++);

    return 0;
}
```

in the command shell I typed `$a  < in.txt > out.txt`

inside in.txt, the content is

```
Hello World

Test File

Here we go
```

I'm expecting the out.txt to have

```
4 arguments

a

Hello World

Test File

Here we go
```

but it turns out that it is

```
1 arguments

a
```

why the redirection from txt to stdin doesn't work?
It seems like < in.txt didn't copy the content to the console at all.

Comment: I stumble with your for-loop. You think have to fix your for-loop like `for (int i = 0; i<argc; i++) { ` a.s.o.

Comment: It's the same as
    `while((*argv)){ 
      print(*(argv));
      argv++;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting input and output with pipes does not populate `argv`; it simply points `stdin` and `stdout` elsewhere, from within the execution environment. This is transparent to your program.

`argv` contains command-line arguments that are passed to the program itself, not the execution environment.

Comment: I don't really understand. Can you elaborate more? What do you mean by points stdin and stdout elsewhere from the environment

Comment: @maple: As Govind said, the I/O redirection symbols (`>` and `<`) and the associated file names are handled by the shell before your program is run, and are not passed as arguments to your program.  Your program is invoked with no user arguments; `argc` will be 1, and `argv[0]` will the program name (probably `a` given your command line).  If your program read from standard input, it could then write the information to standard output — use `fgets()`, for example, to read the lines.

Comment: So how do I redirect a content of file to the console if I'm given a binary file which I can't read?